# Angular 7 como cargar una función cuando este todo lo demas cargado (Funciones Asincronas)

Tags: angular7, asincronismo, async

Tengo  mi `ngOnInit()` en el que cargo :

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.cargarPaises();
    //nuevo form
    this.buildForm();
  }
```

Y en la funcion  `this.buildForm()`  accedo a datos que deben de estar cargados previamente en la **vista**.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la **funcion** `this.buildForm()` se cargue una vez este todo lo demás cargado ?

El error es el siguiente :

```
Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es "observar" esa petición o utilizar simplemente una promesa. Si utilizas una promesa seria algo de este estilo :

```
cargarPaises(): Promise<Country>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)) => {
    this.http.get<Country>('tu-api').subscribe(data => resolve(data));
  }
}
```

luego:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.cargarPaises().then((country) => {
    this.buildForm();
  });
}
```

Si utilizas un observable

```
private subject = new Subject<any>();
cargarPaises(){
  this.http.get<Country>('tu-api').subscribe(data => {
    this.subject.next(data);
  });
}
```

Luego

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subject.asObservable().subscribe(message => {
    this.buildForm(); // se cargara cuando pases algo al subject a través de next()
  });
  this.cargarPaises();
}
```

Si lo necesitas como servicio lo puedes implementar de esta manera e inyectarlo en tu componente

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedProvider {

    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMessage(message: string) {
        this.subject.next({ something: message });
    }

    clearMessage() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Ton, gracias por responder. Mira te comento, la **funcion** `cargarPaises()` es una funcion que precede a la que me refiero y ya esta, es decir, **no interviene en nada en mi pregunta**, simplemente publique mi pregunta poniendolo tal cual lo tengo, imaginate que **no esta esa funcion**. Mi problema es en la funcion `buildForm()`. No obstante muchas gracias por tu respuesta, si la pudieses editar en torno a la aclaracion de este comentario te lo agradeceria. Un saludo.

Comment: no entiendo, puedes ser mas claro? quieres se ejecuten funciones en "cadena", es decir, A B y despues C o necesitas que la informacion que se mostrara en el componente ya este cargada antes del ngOnInit?